# Bootstrap Convert two column layout to four column layout

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

If I have two column in desktop, can I convert this two column into four column in tablet view.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6"></div>
<div class="col-sm-6"></div>
</div>
```

if it is not possible with bootstrap, Is it possible with Tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your div class to `"col-xs-3"` and allocate a width and height.

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/y4dexrrL/1/)

Full code:

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-3">div</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">div</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">div</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">div</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {border: 2px black solid; width:100%;}
```

Have a look at a technique called ['Scaffolding'](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html)

Boostrap 3 also offers a whole new range of features for the grid system and media queries, check out this [blog post](http://blog.templatemonster.com/2014/10/24/bootstrap-3-grid-system-guide/)

Comment: Actually I want two columns in desktop view but 4 columns in tablet view.

Comment: see updated answer. the resource material should get the result you desire.

Comment: so using the resources i gave you implement a media query and change the html class for the div objects with an allocated id through that from col-sm-6 to col-xs-3 and add two div tags for columns inside that query.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div>
```